# Turn on missing @synthesize warning in Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, xcode4.4

I'd like to get back the Xcode 4.3 warning about missing @synthesize commands.  I have a CI environment that hasn't upgraded to Xcode 4.4 yet and without the warning in my Xcode 4.4 I find myself forgetting to do this all the time and then having to go back and correct it once my Xcode 4.3 CI environment's built IPA gets tested.

Please tell me there is a way to turn this back on.

Comment: Add `-Wall` into the compiler flags in the "Build phases" settings of your project.

Comment: Oh and btw +1 for wanting to increase your compiler warning level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a compiler warning for implicitly synthesized properties: `-Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis`. If you turn it on it gives you warnings for declared properties without a matching `@synthesize` or `@dynamic` directive. I find this very useful.

The name of the Xcode build setting is `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_MISSING_PROPERTY_SYNTHESIS` or, in the build settings user interface, **"Implicit Synthesized Properties"**.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it had to be out there but couldn't seem to find it on my own.

Comment: I couldn't seem to find it on my own either, great help.